How to publish library when using custom BOM
I'm having trouble finding the correct way to publish a java library to artifactory when the project uses a custom BOM.
This project has a multi-module structure -
    * my-root
      * my-bom
        * build.gradle
      * my-library
        * src
        * build.gradle
      * my-app 
        * src
        * build.gradle
    * settings.gradle

my-bom/build.gradle has
    plugins {
        id 'java-platform'
    }
    
    javaPlatform {
        allowDependencies()
    }
    
    dependencies {
        api platform('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:2023.0.3')
        api platform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:3.3.4")
        api platform('org.junit:junit-bom:5.11.0')
    
        constraints {
            api 'net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:8.0'
            api "org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:5.13.0"
            api 'commons-io:commons-io:2.17.0'
            ...
            ...
        }
    }

This bom is included in my-library/build.gradle
    plugins {
        id 'java-library'
        id 'com.jfrog.artifactory'
        id 'maven-publish'
    }
    
    dependencies {
        implementation platform(project(':my-bom'))
        implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation"
        implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux"
        ...
        ...
    }

I published the jar using command ./gradlew :my-library:assemble :my-library:publish
This is my artifactory configuration -
    artifactory {
        contextUrl = ...
        publish {
            repository {
                maven = true
                repoKey = ...
                username = ...
                password = ...
    
            }
            defaults {
                publications('mavenJava')
    
            }
    
        }
        resolve {
            repository {
                maven = true
                repoKey = ...
                username = ...
                password = ...
    
            }
        }
    }
    publishing {
        repositories {
            maven {
                credentials {
                    username ...
                    password ...
                }
                url ...
            }
        }
        publications {
            library(MavenPublication) {
                from components.java
            }
        }
    }

I tried to resolve the published the jar in my-app by using implementation(group: 'my-group', name: 'my-library', version: '+') but I get the error -
       > Could not resolve my-group:my-library:v0.0.1.
             > Could not parse POM https://****.jfrog.io/****/my-library/v0.0.1/my-library-v0.0.1.pom
                > Could not find my-root:my-bom:unspecified

When I downloaded the pom, I see
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>my-group</groupId>
      <artifactId>my-library</artifactId>
      <version>v0.0.1</version>
      <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>my-root</groupId>
            <artifactId>my-bom</artifactId>
            <version>unspecified</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </dependencyManagement>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        ...
        ...
      </dependencies>

I tried searching the internet but none of them had the same setup as mine. I tried my modifying their solutions, but couldn't find a the right way to publish the jar.
Please help with the correct way to publish my-library.
gradle = 8.5, 
springboot = 3.3.4, 
jfrog's build-info-extractor-gradle = 4+

